# Stereo Vision for Obstacle Detection

Tags: stereo-3d, disparity-mapping, halcon

I'm working on stereo vision project with Halcon/NET. My project is to scanning the surface of a metal plate. Is it possible to detect small hole(1-3mm) on it with stereo vision?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, with the right optics and the right software.

Comment: can you refer me to the article where I can study on? I'm developing the software tho, but I don't quite understand about stereo vision algorithms, how to calibrate camera and disparity image

Answer (score 0):

If you are somewhat familiar with epipolar geometry and MRF optimization, you can have a look at this classic paper on 'Depth Estimation from Video'.

http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/bao/pub/Consistent_Depth_Maps_Recovery_from_a_Video_Sequence.pdf

For camera calibration, you can use their ACTS software from here -
http://www.zjucvg.net/acts/acts.html

It accepts a video sequence and generates camera parameters and depth maps.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible to detect it - but I doubt you need stereo vision for it. Stereo vision is only useful when you want to recover 3D information (depth) from a scene.

Detection and classification can be achieved through deep learning methods too, it will also be probably more intuitive that way - but it depends on how unique your 'hole' is compared to the background of your scene. A problem of similar novelty has been discussed in this [**paper**](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/mice.12263).

The same problem persists for stereo-vision, if the background of your scene has similar features to what you are trying to 'detect' it will create problems during stereo-matching.

Even if you use a simple 'edge' detector using a monocular vision system, it will still cause a problem.